# I have a question about bubble sort in c++

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple program for an ascending bubble sort. I used a function for it.
It will be built and assign numbers to the array and print the numbers first. but when I choose 'y' it does not do anything. I used the print function in my program in "bubblesort" function but it does not show anything.
I do not know where my problem is.
here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print(int a[],int amount);
void bubblesort(int a[],int amount);
void change(int,int);


int main()
{
    int amount;
    cout << "enter amount " << endl;
    cin >> amount;

    int *p = new int;

    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter " << i + 1 << " number" << endl;
        cin >> p[i];
    }
    print(p,amount);

    int choosebubble;
    cout << "do you want to do bubblesort? y " << endl;
    cin >> choosebubble;
    if(choosebubble == 'y' || choosebubble == 'Y')
           bubblesort(p,amount);

    return 0;
}

void print(int a[],int amount)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
   {
       cout << "number " << i + 1 << " is : " << a[i] << endl;
   }
}

void change(int *x,int *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void bubblesort(int a[],int amount)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < amount-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < amount-1; j++)
        {
            if(a[j] > a[j+1])
                change(a+j ,a + j + 1);

        }
    }
    print(a,amount);
}
```

Comment: You've declared `choosebubble` as `int`, then you tell the user to insert `y` or `Y`.

Comment: Why do you dynamically allocate a single integer, `p`?  In C++ you don't need to dynamically allocate a variable (unless you are doing things like making linked lists).

Comment: Don't use arrays.  Use `std::vector`.  You allocate memory for **one** integer, and yet store more integers beyond the single integer location.  In most programming languages, you either allocated an array for many integers or using a dynamic container.

Answer (score 2):

Two erros here:

First one:

```
int *p = new int;
```

will allocate exactly *one* integer on the heap, not an array. Any access to `p` that uses an index other than 0 results in undefined behaviour. You meant

```
int *p = new int[amount];
```

And here's the obligatory note, that `std::vector<int>` should be preferred ;)

Secondly:

```
int choosebubble;
cin >> choosebubble;
```

will try to read an `int`, but you want a `char`, declare it as such:

```
char choosebubble;
cin >> choosebubble;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your types. `choosebubble` is an `int`, but you want a `char`acter, so use a `char` (see also [`std::istream::operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)).

By default, getting a number will convert the input into a number. If you don't want that, use a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int choosebubble;
cin >> choosebubble;
if(choosebubble == 'y' || choosebubble == 'Y')
           bubblesort(p,amount);
```

You know, for this to work, you'd have to input the ASCII code of letter 'y' (121, or 89 for capitalized). You probably want to declare `choosebubble` as `char` (or `std::string`, but then, compare against `"y"` or `"Y"`).

Answer (score 0):

Like Enrico Maria De Angelis said in the comments, you've declared `choosebubble` to be `int`, but then you're assigning it the `character` `y` or `Y`. So, when you use `cin` to put something into an `int` but you give it something incompatible (a `character`) what it does is that it apparently puts 0 in your int variable (`choosebubble`) and just sets the `failbit` of the `cin` stream (`cin.fail()`). That's why `bubblesort` is never called.